# Java Spring Boot no bean found using @Bean annotation on default methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I'm having this error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I have tried a lot of things from browsing the web and nothing seems to work.

Im running Redis at port 6379 on ubuntu and this is my java config file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;

import restsimulator.cpo.dto.Version;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    
    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, Version> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Version> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
    
}
```

These are the dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: As M. Deinum suggested in the comments, it was a problem with JPA classpath which triggers the setup of a JDBC DataSource. After removing this from my POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The error no longer occurs. Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is my quess, try making those methods as `public`

Comment: Have you actually read the error message? It is complaining about your datasource, not about the beans you have heard. So you probably have a JDBC driver (or jdbc/jpa related classes) on your classpath which triggers the setup of a JDBC DataSource.